# Using JDBC from Tomcat on Debian server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, debian, tomcat7

I have a Debian server. 
I'm trying to run a JSP website on it. I use `MySQL` and `Tomcat 7.0.54`.

Now here is my problem:
When I send the form with all the data, I get this ERROR:

```
No connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?user=root&password=*****
```

In the terminal I could access to the DB.

Here my code:

```
package com.ubs.jdbc;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

 public class DBConnector
{

private static Connection con = null;

// HIER DEN CONNECT STRING ANPASSEN //
private String connectString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/swissskills?user=root2&password=swissskills";  /* CHANGE */

private Connection openConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
        con = DriverManager.getConnection( connectString ); 
        return con;
    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( "No connection to " + connectString ); 
    }
    return null;
}

public static Connection getConnection()
{
    if( con == null )
    {
        return new DBConnector().openConnection();
    }
    return con;
}

public static void closeConnection()
{
    try
    {
        getConnection().close();
        con = null;
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( "CLOSE CONNECTION: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your JDBC connect code first.

Comment: You should call e.printStackTrace() when catch exception, also post your stack trace result.

Comment: Try removing user and password from your `connectString` and call `DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, user, password);`

Comment: Did you add the MySQL JDBC driver jar file to Tomcat's /lib folder? If you printed the stack trace as suggested above by Jason, we could know whether that's the problem or not, as you'd get a `ClassNotFoundException` upon calling `Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" )`

Comment: Thank's for your answers.
I added a driver to the lib folder. But I'm not sure if it is the right one for debian. 

As soon as I'm back in my office I will put in the StackTrace.

Answer (score 0):

Install Mysql JDBC

```
# apt-get install libmysql-java
```

Set environment for all user /etc/environment:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
CLASSPATH=".:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar:/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc4.jar"
```

**Note**: change /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 with your installed JDK

Test your connection using this code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.Properties;

class TestDB {

    /*

      /usr/share/java

      http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/

      https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/documentation.html

    */

   static Connection conn = null;   

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // MySQL

      try {

         System.out.println("Loading Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;

         System.out.println("Loading com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Successful");

         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?user=user&password=password");

         // Do something with the Connection

         System.out.println("Test Connection Successful");

      } catch (SQLException ex) {

         // handle any errors

         System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());

         System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());

         System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());

      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

         System.out.println("Class Not Found: " + ex.getMessage());

      }
   }
}
```

**Note**: change database, user and password with your connection setting

http://www.garasiku.web.id/web/joomla/index.php/java/112-debian-jessie-installing-openjdk-8-mysql-jdbc-and-postgresql-jdbc